how to source a file in maven
I have a shell script that I want maven to source. I specifically want maven to source the file (source run.sh) rather than just executing it (./run.sh)
I have tried 2 different approaches with 2 different plugins and neither work:
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>source file</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>source</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>./run.sh</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

and
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>source file</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <exec executable="source">
                        <arg value="./run.sh"/>
                    </exec>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

They both fail saying that the command source does not exist

First I would ask why do you need that? Second sourcing only works on the current instance of the bash/shell... but using exec or alike will create everytime a new instance of shell/bash?

@khmarbaise The file I want to source sets environment variables and aliases that I need to reference in a subsequent command afterwards. I don't have control over this file b/c the commands inside it are constantly changing, so I need to source it in order to capture its environment variables dynamically.

That will not work, as I mentioned before during the exeuction of either exec-maven-plugin or maven-antrun-plugin the ./run.sh will create a new instance of shell/bash and after finished the ./run.sh it remove the instance... with it's environment variables... .. Why do you need aliases for a Maven build? You have to run that before the whole Maven build....

@khmarbaise Thank you. I found that the best solution for me was to create a shell script that contains all the commands I wanted to execute. Then I can have a maven plugin execute my script once instead of trying to execute each command individually in a maven plugin.

I based my answer on @walyrious idea. I execute bash -c 'source run.sh; custom-script.sh' in maven-antrun-plugin so that custom-script.sh is in the same shell as the sourced run.sh. Though, I think this maven execution is much cleaner than his answer:
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>source file</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <exec executable="bash">
                        <arg line="-c 'source run.sh; custom-script.sh'"/>
                    </exec>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


Here's a solution that may be helpful at least as a workaround. TL;DR: The gist of my this trick is to use the equivalent of bash -c "source foobar" instead of source foobar directly, since source is a shell builtin and not an executable file.
(Disclaimer: In my case I had to adapt a Maven project that was created by someone else, and was set up to use the exec-maven-plugin to install a Python dependency and run a Python script. I needed to run the commands within a virtual environment, and thus needed to run the typical source myenv/bin/activate command. The solution below is likely a kludge and not the ideal way to make this work)
Here's what the pom.xml had before (It assumed python3 and pip3 are already available):
</plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <executions>

            <execution>
                <id>install-python-dependencies</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>pip3</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                        <argument>-r</argument>
                        <argument>path/to/requirements.txt</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>run-python-script</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>python3</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>path/to/custom-script.py</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

and here's how I adapted it to use source to set up a virtual environment:
</plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <executions>

            <execution>
                <id>create-python-virtual-environment</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>python3</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-m</argument>
                        <argument>venv</argument>
                        <argument>my_local_env</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>install-python-dependencies</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>bash</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-c</argument>
                        <argument>source my_local_env/bin/activate &amp;&amp; pip3 install -r path/to/requirements.txt</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>run-python-script</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>python3</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>path/to/custom-script.py</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

The changes done are as follows:

A preliminary execution, named create-python-virtual-environment, was added at the start to, well, create a virtual environment
The install-python-dependencies execution was modified to execute pip3 install within this virtual environment, which is activated via the source shell builtin

This second step required a few tricks to work:

The bash -c "source <some-script>" pattern was used to call source rather than have source be the value for the <executable> element directly (which fails, as you describe)

(If anyone's wondering, Python virtual environments must be activated via source mylocalenv/bin/activate; directly running the mylocalenv/bin/activate script does not work.)


The sourcing of the virtual environment and the pip3 install call were combined in the install-python-dependencies execution, since each execution happens in an isolated shell, and the virtual environment that is set up would no longer be active if the next command was executed separately.

Note: since this is a XML document, the && operator had to be escaped as &amp;&amp;



Again, I am NOT recommending this as a clean or desirable solution, but I'm sharing it here in case it helps out someone else as a quick workaround.
